# Getting position from item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform, position

I can't get the position of the button in my Listview.

This is my code:

```
public View getItemView( final Photo ParsePhoto, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.main_item, null);
        }
        super.getItemView(ParsePhoto, v, parent);
```

Because of the ParsPhoto, I can't get the position of the item. I have tried this:

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Item clicked: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getClass().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "ActiviyInt" + position);
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't run. Why does this not work? Is there another method to get the position of the item?

Comment: Try this toast `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Item clicked: " + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` to get the position

Comment: What does "it doesn't run" mean? If there's a stack trace, show it.

Comment: @ci_ It means that i don't get Log: "AcitvityInt 2", as if i didn't click. The setOnItemClickListener doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide appropriate code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the context class name.this and this listener into on create method.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean :/